Apple Configurator and paid apps
I purchased some paid apps using my Apple ID. Recently, I discovered that I can use Apple Configurator to install these paid apps on any iOS device, even if the device is not logged in with my Apple ID. After installation, the apps can still run normally. This is beyond my expectations. Shouldn't Apple protect the copyright of these paid apps and prevent them from being installed on devices that haven't paid for them?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
